# Create a welcome message in the discord bot in js when a new member enters

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create in my discord bot a "Welcome" message when a new user logs in and for some reason it does not work, there is no error message and the like.
Attaching the code, I would really love to help.

```
  client.on('GulidMemberAdd', (member)  => { console.error("work?")
  let channelId = '814448374790225980'; 
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('member joined!')
  .setDescription('${member.user.tag} join')
  .setTimestamp()
  client.channels.cache.get(channelId).send(embed)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 typos in your code.

```js
client.on('gulidMemberAdd', (member)  => { 
//         ~~~~~ should be guild
  let channelId = '814448374790225980'; 
  let embed = new Discord.MeesageEmbed()
//                        ~~~~~~~ should be Message
  .setTitle('member joined!')
//                ~                       ~ Should be a template literal string
  .setDescription('${member.user.tag} join')
  .setTimestamp()
  client.channels.cache.get(channelId).send(embed)
})
```

Fixed version:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member)  => { 
  let channelId = '814448374790225980'; 
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('member joined!')
  .setDescription(`${member.user.tag} join`)
  .setTimestamp()
  client.channels.cache.get(channelId).send(embed)
})
```

Comment: I changed the fix I said and it still does not work
I also added a console message at the beginning of the code section and it does not even print it, apparently the code does not even run when a new user enters the server and I do not understand why, I would be happy to help

Comment: I have figured it out: You also made a typo in the event name. See my edit.

Comment: client.on('GulidMemberAdd', (member)  => {

Comment: I also fixed the event name and still it does not even print the console message right at the beginning of the code

Comment: is the event name exactly `'guildMemberAdd'`?

Comment: Yes I copied the code exactly as it appears here

Comment: I didn't actually make changes to the code, I just added comments to show what needs to be done. Give me a second for me to edit my answer.

Comment: No need to allow me, it's automatic. See my edit.

Comment: Really thanks it does work, but why does it not print my username instead of the string? See attached link
https://prnt.sc/108yx77

Comment: That is a string literal (`'`). For template literals (that is, `${}`), you need to use backticks (the symbol used 3 times to indicate code, it looks like this: `)

Comment: If this answered your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Is there an option to ask if you could give me an example of how I actually do that it will work?

Comment: My username works, thanks
How do I mark your answer as an answer that helped me?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) shows how to do it.

Comment: Just thought I'd note for others that come by here, if you're using discord.js v12+ you'll also need to explicitly include the GUILD_MEMBERS intent in order to use the guildMemberAdd event: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents and https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents

Comment: Maybe you have a solution for that too please? No one answers me
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66405466/create-an-auto-roll-for-each-new-user-in-the-dhscord-js-bot