# Create an auto-roll for each new user in the dhscord.js bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I wrote a code that should create an automatic roll for me as soon as a new user is added to my server (feel in a roll system called member)
There are errors in the code, I would love if someone could help me and fix the problem. Thank you.
I attached the code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

  client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member)  => { 
    let welcomeRole = member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'member');
    member.roles.add(welcomeRole);

  })
```

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you enabled Guild Member intents?

Comment: I did not really understand what you meant
But this event works for me when a new user logs in (appears welcome)
Just do not add the roll

Comment: Please read the following: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html

Comment: This is the error I get, link attached
https://prnt.sc/1098msw

Comment: Note that welcome roles are not recommended, as it allows users to bypass the Server Verification Level and New Member Screening features.

Comment: Thanks this is really true, I will also create some verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are finding the role `'member'` from `member.guild.roles` not `member.roles`.
Second, make sure you have declared all [intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents) to send and receive the right data to Discord API.

**Add any more intents that your other functions will need.**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = Discord.Client({ ws: { intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MEMBERS'] } });

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member)  => { 
    let welcomeRole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'member');
    member.roles.add(welcomeRole);
});
```

Comment: I could not figure out how the syntcx works
I changed my code up, I would be very happy if you could edit it

Comment: @חייםאבלס What specific part of the syntax?

Comment: You added in reading to Discord intents, if I write in the way you said it completely ignores me the code

Comment: I'm trying to create an event that as soon as a new user is added to the server it will automatically get a roll, if you know another way it's also good for me, at the moment I can not

Comment: @חייםאבלס Do you mean it's giving an error?

Comment: No, if I write the instens in the call to Discord then from that moment the bot does not respond to anything at all (even to events that did work)

Comment: Go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and navigate to your application -> Bot. Toggle on 'SERVER MEMBERS INTENT'. This is part of the intents documentation.

Comment: Can you please help me? I'm at a loss